# Would you use a UITableViewController to implement a check list on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, user-interface

I am creating an application that will have a list of items that can be checked.  I just implemented it as a Table View by subclassing UITableViewController.  Now I am realizing that since individual items don't have a child view (i.e. clicking on an item "Dinner" does not need to pull up a child list of "Dinner Items") then maybe I should have just created a custom view for the list.

In your experience, would it be better to use the Table View or create something custom?

thanks!

p.s. I am a bit new to iPhone dev, but NOT new to C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO, using a UITableViewController subclass is the go-to solution for a dynamically sized list of things, because it's easily scrollable, indexable, and has bunches of convenient method hooks predefined for you (and is relatively leak-free and very well tested). I'd stick with it unless you have a good reason for doing otherwise. Even though you don't need subviews, there are still several strong advantages in using a UITableViewController.

Comment: Makes sense.  That's why I used it in the first place - it was really easy.

Comment: btw, i did go this route and proved very useful.